# Nested ifs in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and have only been using it for a couple of months.  I've basically been learning as I go.  Despite that, I'm trying to write some code to care for a variety of functions.  I have written the code below that is launched from a command button on a userform.  The code basically is supposed to search a row in an Excel worksheet and verify a couple of pieces of information and then take action.  If the code cannot verify a match between entries on the row and entries in the userform, it stops and displays an error message.  If it can verify the information match, it is supposed to proceed with populating some information on that row.  I realize that this code I've written is probably completely hamfisted and decidedly un-elegant, however it was working until I added the validation for the product code.  Please, can someone help?  I've looked and looked and cannot find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub AddDelivButton_Click()

Sheets("Deliveries").Activate

Dim number As Integer, rownumber As Integer, result As Long, i As Integer
number = POTextBox.Value
rownumber = 0
result = 1000000
For i = 1 To 25000
If Cells(i, 1).Value = number Then
    result = Cells(i, 1).Value
    rownumber = i
End If
Next i
If result = 1000000 Then
    MsgBox "PO Number Not Found"
    Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Cells(rownumber, 1).Select

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(3).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(5).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(7).Select
            If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
                MsgBox "Product Code Not Found"
                Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
                Exit Sub
              Else
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(10).Select
                If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = ProdCodeListBox1.Value
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(11).Value = WeightTextBox1.Value
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(12).Value = DateTextBox1.Value
                  Else
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(13).Select
                    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = ProdCodeListBox1.Value
                        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(14).Value = WeightTextBox1.Value
                        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(15).Value = DateTextBox1.Value
                      Else
```

This goes on for several iterations and to save space I have not included all of them here.  Suffice it to say that the last two if statements were working until I added the validation for the ProdCodeListBox1.

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Even if it is something simple I am overlooking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your current code you check cells 3, 5 and 7 for a matching value and display an error if none of them match then exit the Sub altogether. You only go on to check cell 10 if cell 7 has a match. If cells 3 or 5 match you never get to the check on cell 10

Try this instead:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(3).Select

If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(5).Select

    If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(7).Select

        If ActiveCell.Value <> ProdCodeListBox1.Value Then
            MsgBox "Product Code Not Found"
            Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(10).Select
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
```

All of the `ActiveCell` and `Select` business isn't the best way to get the values from specific cells but that's a different question

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  That was easy and solved the problem immediately.  I understand your comment on ActiveCell and Select.  I've basically been teaching myself as I go but I want to learn to code more efficiently as well. Unfortunately sometimes I learn things after I've already written so many lines I don't want to go back and redo!